# Why won't my video seek on my website whether I use video.js or not?

Tags: video, video.js, progress, seek

I have a video hosting website and I recently transferred it from a shared server from Hostinger to a dedicated server on NameCheap in order to use FFMPEG and allow for much larger uploads.

I am using video.js to play videos. On long videos such as this one - https://feminuremberg.com/video.php?v=184 if I click anywhere on the progress bar, the video just plays back from the beginning. It will not seek to the time I want.

When the video is not using video.js, it will not seek at all. https://feminuremberg.com/test2.php

I never had this problem back on the Shared server at Hostinger. Whenever I clicked on a certain time in the progress bar, the video will start playing at that time, even if it has to load a bit to buffer there.

Is this a code issue or does this have to do with some settings on my new dedicated server? If this has something to do with the code, what code should I use to fix this?

I tried:

```
<video id="myVideo#t=20" controls onseeking="myFunction()" onseeked="myFunction()">
  <source src="vvv184.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

to give it a head start but it still starts from the beginning.